# Postfix errors: No TLS, EmptyCertificate and Mail received as unauthenticated, incoming to a recipient domain configured in a hosted tenant

Tags: centos, postfix

Previously, there were errors with Postfix complaining about no `[No TLS]`

```
Jul 14 10:37:38 q03pmds postfix/smtp[81151]: A02F3FF9F4: host pel-com-au.mail.protection.outlook.com[104.47.71.202] said: 451 4.4.62 Mail sent to the wrong Office 365 region. ATTR35. For more information please go to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865268 [No TLS] [ME3AUS01FT018.eop-AUS01.prod.protection.outlook.com 2023-07-14T00:37:38.115Z 08DB8303CE4A917A] (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

I have create a sign-signed certificate and added in the Postfix configuration file as below:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/postfix.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/private/postfix.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_security_level = may
```

However, I am now getting `[ValidationStatus of '' is EmptyCertificate]`

```
(host epl-com-au.mail.protection.outlook.com[104.47.71.202] said: 451 4.4.62 Mail sent to the wrong Office 365 region. ATTR35. For more information please go to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865268 [ValidationStatus of '' is EmptyCertificate] [ME3AUS01FT009.eop-AUS01.prod.protection.outlook.com 2023-07-17T00:39:37.165Z 08DB85E60F9C36B4] (in reply to end of DATA command))

(host epl-com-au.mail.protection.outlook.com[104.47.71.138] said: 451 4.4.62 Mail sent to the wrong Office 365 region. ATTR35. For more information please go to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865268 [ValidationStatus of '' is EmptyCertificate] [SY4AUS01FT012.eop-AUS01.prod.protection.outlook.com 2023-07-17T00:39:37.165Z 08DB858C5B8F4556] (in reply to end of DATA command))

(host epl-com-au.mail.protection.outlook.com[104.47.71.138] said: 451 4.4.62 Mail sent to the wrong Office 365 region. ATTR35. For more information please go to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865268 [ValidationStatus of '' is EmptyCertificate] [SY4AUS01FT011.eop-AUS01.prod.protection.outlook.com 2023-07-17T00:39:37.375Z 08DB864D666BFE0D] (in reply to end of DATA command))

(host epl-com-au.mail.protection.outlook.com[104.47.71.202] said: 451 4.4.4 Mail received as unauthenticated, incoming to a recipient domain configured in a hosted tenant which has no mail-enabled subscriptions. ATTR5 [ME3AUS01FT004.eop-AUS01.prod.protection.outlook.com 2023-07-17T00:39:37.237Z 08DB85FB7229EDD0] (in reply to end of DATA command))

(host epl-com-au.mail.protection.outlook.com[104.47.71.138] said: 451 4.4.4 Mail received as unauthenticated, incoming to a recipient domain configured in a hosted tenant which has no mail-enabled subscriptions. ATTR5 [SY4AUS01FT024.eop-AUS01.prod.protection.outlook.com 2023-07-17T00:39:37.320Z 08DB85FB7C2C75CE] (in reply to end of DATA command))

(host epl-com-au.mail.protection.outlook.com[104.47.71.202] said: 451 4.4.62 Mail sent to the wrong Office 365 region. ATTR35. For more information please go to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865268 [ValidationStatus of '' is EmptyCertificate] [ME3AUS01FT013.eop-AUS01.prod.protection.outlook.com 2023-07-17T00:39:37.711Z 08DB860FE83B4875] (in reply to end of DATA command))

(host epl-com-au.mail.protection.outlook.com[104.47.71.138] said: 451 4.4.4 Mail received as unauthenticated, incoming to a recipient domain configured in a hosted tenant which has no mail-enabled subscriptions. ATTR5 [SY4AUS01FT010.eop-AUS01.prod.protection.outlook.com 2023-07-17T00:39:37.463Z 08DB85D292FA106C] (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

I am also getting a bunch of `Mail received as unauthenticated, incoming to a recipient domain configured in a hosted tenant which has no mail-enabled subscriptions. ATTR5`.

I have configured the Office 365 connector to accept emails from the Postfix server, SPF record and added an A record for the Postfix server hostname.

I am not getting any certificates when running `openssl s_client`

```
 openssl s_client -connect localhost:25
CONNECTED(00000003)
140466906908560:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 289 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1689557445
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Fixed the certificate warning by adding the following:

```
smtp_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/postfix.pem
smtp_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/private/postfix.key
```